# configuration of a maven project with sub project to access all java facilities

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, configuration

I have a mavent parent project with maven child project using microservices within Eclipse. But I don't have access to all java facilities and information. For example the type of compiler and java libraries or JRE information are not available. Other example, I cannot right click on a method and go to its implementation. When I right click on the project and go to properties, I have the following image.

[image]

### EDIT

.project file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
    <name>immobilier</name>
    <comment></comment>
    <projects>
    </projects>
    <buildSpec>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Builder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
    </buildSpec>
    <natures>
        <nature>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Nature</nature>
    </natures>
</projectDescription>
```

Comment: Did you import it as a maven projekt. If not it won’t work.

Comment: Yes I imported it as a maven project. See EDIT

Comment: Do it again in a fresh workspace and without any existing configuration files.

Answer (score 0):

I did it in a new workspace

[image]

[image]

It is OK for all sub-modules and I haven't any more the parent module (is it normal ?). Furthermore I haven't the module user-service, a module that I have added during development and not yet saved on git

Comment: finally, I make appear user-service changing its pom.xml. The post is Closed